# Short science fiction film about a Midwest farmer who builds a bunker after finding a space plant

Tags: story-identification, short-film

This was a short film about some sort of items or plants/seeds sent to Earth. I remember a guy (like a Midwest farmer-style or something like that) found one.

He starts acting strange, building sort of a bunker container and is tracked by some sort of secret agent trying to get that item.

At the end of the film he puts his daughter with another dude and that item inside it. Then it is sort of the end of the world (post-apocalyptic style) but the magical plant from space is spreading out of that built container. During the destruction of Earth that organic matter sort of spreads inside the container to protect itself and the girl by creating a sort of cocoon.

Also that space magical plant or item fixed/healed a guy with broken legs or something similar in the middle of the movie.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this one was closed as a duplicate accidentally: the movie in the target has the same title but is from a different decade and has a very different plot summary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for an Australian science fiction film [*named Terminus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminus_(2015_film)), as many of your details match:

- Nuclear war at the end, only the daughter and another survive
- War veteran with amputated leg has it regenerated
- Item from space is encased in an abandoned factory
- Tailed by government agents to find item from space
- Main character is a small town citizen
- Emergence from factory at end is into world covered in vegetation

Comment: OMG YES !! Thank you so much John you are the best mate. That was driving me crazy. It is the first time ever i can not remember and find something i really have in mind, that was so frustrating...to the point that for the first time ever i posted something online to ask for help. Thanks again and to anyone take a minute to watch it it is actually very good :)